# Не могу получить доступ к NavMesh

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу получить доступ к методам НавМэш из скрипта. На данный момент только запек НавМэш и ещё не создавал агента (возможная причина). Запекал через меню Навигации, а не через сурфейс.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто прописать:

```
using UnityEngine.AI
```